# Magento Admin Panel graphics not showing

Tags: admin, admin-panel

[image: Admin Panel]

So after upgrading Magento to 1.9.1 the Admin panel is working but in displaying a white background with the URL links. It seems to appear like a site map of the admin panel. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do with open the table `core_config_data`,

correct the values for the paths `web/unsecure/base_url` and web/secure/base_url. Make sure `dev/js/merge_files` and `dev/css/merge_css_files` are both 0.

Clear the cache by deleting all files in `var/cache/` in your Magento directory

Also make sure and clean your browser `cache` and `cookies`

hope this will work for you.

Comment: I also tried your method but was unable to get the Admin panel to display with CSS

Answer (score 1):

It's the admin panel without CSS. Look at the HTML source ("View Source" in your browser") and check the URLs of the CSS files.

If it is something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/var/www/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
```

(i.e. no URL with `http://` but a path on the file system), then it is because you have enabled the "Merge CSS Files" configuration but your `media/css` and `media/css_secure` directories are not writable, so Magento cannot store the merged files.

Make sure, your web server has write permissions for `media`, this will fix it.

Comment: This did not work. I have permissions set properly to 755, also CSS and JS are set to not merge.